# Estruturas de Repetição em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

recentemente iniciei os meus estudos na programação e estava fazendo um exercício do URI no qual eu tenho que ler um conjunto não determinado de de valores M e N, onde para cada par lido, mostre a sequência do menor até o maior e a soma dos inteiros consecutivos entre eles (incluindo o N e M). Pensando em qual a melhor maneira de resolver me surgiu a seguinte dúvida, é possível fazer um laço de repetição dentro de uma Estrutura Condicional? Pois eu conseguir resolver esse problema de uma maneira mais simples, porém seguindo uma lógica parecida com estruturas de repetição eu não consigo de jeito nenhum apresentar o resultado correto.
Segue o link da questão: https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1101

```
 M = int(input(""))
 N = int(input(""))

 soma = 0

 while True:
    if (M <= 0 or N <= 0):
       break

  if (M >= N):
     for N in range(N, M, 1):
        print(N)
        soma = soma + N
  else:
    for M in range(M, N, 1):
        print(M)
        soma = soma + M

print(soma)

M = int(input(""))
N = int(input(""))
```

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e cole o `link` da questão. Então, poderemos ler o enunciado e lhe ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro detalhe é que os valores de M e N serão lidos no mesmo `input`, não separadamente.

```py
limits = input()
M, N = map(int, limits.split())
```

Você pode construir o seu laço sempre partindo do M até o N, mas caso M for maior, inverter os valores:

```py
if M > N:
  M, N = N, M
```

Código ficaria assim:

```py
while True:
    limites = input()
    M, N = map(int, limites.split())

    if M <= 0 or N <= 0:
        break
    
    if M > N:
        M, N = N, M

    soma = 0
    for numero in range(M, N+1):
        print(numero, end=' ')
        soma += numero
    print(f'Sum={soma}')
```

Podendo simplificar ainda mais se desejar, mas isso deixo como tarefa de casa para você.

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de se resolver esta questão é:

```
# uri 1101
while True:
    M, N = list(map(int, input().split()))

    if M <= 0 or N <= 0:
        break
    else:
        menor = min(M, N)
        maior = max(M, N)

        soma = 0
        for c in range(menor, maior + 1):
            soma += c
            print(c, end=' ')
        print(f'Sum={soma}')
```

Observe que quando executamos este código a tela do programa fica escura com o `cursor` piscando no canto superior esquerdo. Neste momento devemos digitar os valores **M** e **N**, na **mesma** linha, **separados** por um só espaço e pressionar `enter`.

A partir deste momento o algoritmo realizará todas as tarefas e exibirá os resultados.